# How do I set a static IP for my iPad?

Tags: ipad, wifi, network

I have an iPad v1 and need to plug in its IP to a program on my computer to test files.

The problem is every time I connect, the IP is reset and I have to enter a new IP.

Is there a way to have it permanently on one IP?

Answer (score 1):

Settings --> WiFi --> select the network --> select Static and set the necessary values

Answer (score 0):

In your router you should be able to statically assign an IP address for the iPad based on its MAC address.